# Surjective open map requirements

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be surjective and open map.
I should prove that $f$ is a factor map. 
It's obviously if $f$ is continuous, but is this still true if we don't require that?

Comment: What's the definition of a factor map? (I expect that it's just another word for a quotient map, in which case the continuity is part [or direct consequence] of the definition.)

Comment: Also, open maps are often defined to be continuous as well.

Comment: Yes i mean quotient map.
Sorry

Comment: I have also seen the convention that *map* (in a topological setting) means *continuous function*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective and open (in the strict sense of mapping open sets to open sets) then we can easily see that

$$ \forall O \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[O] \text{ open } \rightarrow O \text{ open.}$$

The proof is simply that $O = f[f^{-1}[O]]$ by surjectivity and the latter is open as $f$ is open.

The reverse implication (which is necessary for being a quotient map) is exactly continuity so can only be proved if we assume $f$ was continuous to start with. Otherwise the identity from the reals in the usual topology to the reals in the discrete topology is an example of an open surjection that is not a quotient map.

Alternatively (although I've never seen this) being a factor map could have been defined as this one implication we *can* prove.